# Time difference in transmission of AC and DC

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-circuits, electric-current

Is there any time difference while considering the transmission of AC and DC ? Is either one of them faster than the other one in terms of transmission of energy/power from one point to another?

I mean to say that suppose there are two power stations very very far apart, if one station turns on the switch for the transmission to start, would it matter that DC has constant field, and AC has alternating field for the time taken in transferring energy from one station to another ?

Addendum : to elaborate the question i would add that as current in DC is related to drift velocity of electrons which is not invloved in the transmission during AC, my question is rather related to the flow of electrons. To clarify a little more, do the electrons present right at the tip of the other point of transmission cover same distance while vibrating(travelling distance of amplitude) or drifting in same time ?

Comment: Per our discussion in Meta, this is a good example of a question that is not very clear, seemingly random, and totally unresearched.

Comment: Actually this question was not intended for here, I googled the propogation of the 2 currents, but could not draw any conclusion, so I posted it here. I am open to any and all suggestions to improve it, but do believe me I have searched it over net and could nkt find appropriate answer.

Comment: If I shine two flashlights at you, one with a constant beam, and the other with a pulsating beam, which beam would you see first?

Comment: I understand you are implying that the electric field in both cases would be travelling with same speed, I am in complete agreement, but my question regards the transmission of current.

Comment: If you're asking if AC is *more efficient* than DC for power transmission, then you should state that in the question!  There's certainly plenty of [material](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_Currents) [about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power_transmission) [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current) on the web.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no difference at all in terms of speed. Both will travel at the speed in which light travels on the medium. The only difference is in the efficiency of the power transfer. You should read about the basics of [DC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_current) and [AC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) as it would be repetitive and meaningless to have a full explanation here. Good Luck!

Comment: Doesnt it matter that one of the field is time dependent while other is constant? Explain here if possible. I am asking for explanation because while studying the two, I could not find about the propogation time difference of fhe two currents. Drift velocity is mentioned in case of DC but not much is said for comparison

Comment: @rijulgupta No: think about Fourier theorem/  d'Alembert's formula: the step function of DC can be thought of as the superposition of waves;  assuming that we're ignoring any dispersion in the wire, they all travel with the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that there would be zero difference ideally in transmission of both the currents. In real life transmission systems though you have to consider a bunch of things, one of them being the capacitance of the transmission lines. The capacitance limits how fast the voltage responds at the far end of a power line when voltage is applied at the near end. Capacitance has only a small transient effect on a DC power transmission line, delaying the voltage rise at the far end of the line by a very short amount of time (usually microseconds or milliseconds). But the capacitance of an AC transmission line can have a great impact since the voltage 'reverses' itself periodically. Hence, in practical systems, there is some delay between AC and DC systems.

As the other answer perfectly explains though, if talking only about the actual mechanisms rather than the entire transmission systems, there would be no difference. Hope this answers your query.